# Pass data with an image using web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-web-api, arrays, httpresponsemessage

I need to pass an image within a json response.
Here's my controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetStudents()
    {
        var data = db.Students.ToList();
        return Ok(data);
    }
```

That code obviously returns all the data for each student and returns the student_image column as varbinary but I need it to be passed as an image.

I can return the image if it's the only thing to be returned, and here's the code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetStudentImages(string id)
    {
        var img = (from s in db.Students select new { s.student_image, s.student_id }).Where(a => a.student_id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage();

        if (img == null)
        {
            result.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        }
        else
        {
            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(img.student_image);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

How can I pass the image inside the response ? Thanks.

Comment: You forgot adding to the beginning of `else` the following: `result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);`

Comment: The GetStudentImages works properly. The problem is when I return it inside the list.

Comment: The GetStudents returns a list of the data of the students including the image however it displays as a varbinary not an actual image.

Comment: What's `GetStudentImages` related to `GetStudents` ?

Comment: The GetStudentImages retrieves the images only while the GetStudents retrieves all data related to Students.

Comment: Then no relationship. And you want to return a List of images ?

Comment: Wouldn't you rather return the URI of each image in the list? Makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will return a list of StudentModel which is composed of a `Image` property that contains each image byte array.

```
public class StudentModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ImageModel Image { get; set; }
}

public class ImageModel
{
    public string ContentType { get; private set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; private set; }

    public ImageModel(string contentType, byte[] content)
    {
        ContentType = contentType;
        Content = content;
    }
}

public IHttpActionResult GetStudents()
{
    var data = db.Students.Select(
        student => new StudentModel
        {
            Name = student.Name,
            Image = new ImageModel("image/jpeg", student.student_image)
        }
    );
    return Ok(data);
}
```